# Pacman is broken

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

It's not the first time, but pacman broke down today again. I don't really know how to fix it. So any helpful pointers for me to self-teach will be highly appreciated. I hope I can be an independent arch user.

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
downloading core.db...
downloading extra.db...
downloading community.db...
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: installing xorgproto (2019.2-2) breaks dependency 'dmxproto' required by libdmx
:: installing xorgproto (2019.2-2) breaks dependency 'xf86dgaproto' required by libxxf86dga
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
```

Answer (score 6):

This error has nothing to do with pacman breaking down again. The latest news at https://www.archlinux.org/ shows you how to upgrade your system if you encounter this error.

Comment: Thank you! I did google but did not get useful info. I will check archlinux.org in the future!

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem

Solution [xorg-cleanup-requires-manual-intervention](https://www.archlinux.org/news/xorg-cleanup-requires-manual-intervention/)

```
pacman -Rdd libdmx libxxf86dga && pacman -Syu
```

These links might be helpful as well

[FS#64892 - [Xorg] remove dead Xorg packages](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64892)

[xorgproto issues..](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251517)

Comment: It works! Thank you! Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/edadrc/xorg_cleanup_requires_manual_intervention/

Comment: What I'm more interested in is how did you solve this? After you pointing this out, I noticed that I could have found the news on the homepage of arch and also reddit. However, when things broke down, I thought I messed things up. I tried to remove the packages that cause troubles, but pacman cried for another dependency issue. I was not sure if it would have caused more and more troubles. I also googled my issue, but was not directly led to the news. It felt discouraging. At the end of the day, the issue is that I still lack of understanding of archlinux. That makes me dependent ...

Comment: ...dependent to others. Would you mind telling me how you solved this problem independently? What have you tried when things broke down? Have you once thought perhaps you messed things up, or it was clear to you that it must be "others' fault"? If it was clear to you, what made you different from me? Should I read/follow certain things in order to improve?

Comment: Hey mate check out this link . Though the question addresses only Ubuntu the steps in general apply to all Linux distro https://askubuntu.com/questions/879910/how-to-identify-a-bug-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

**Xorg cleanup requires manual intervention**

To perform the upgrade enter the following command:

```
sudo pacman -Rdd libdmx libxxf86dga libxxf86misc && sudo pacman -Syu
```

or

```
sudo pacman -Rdd libdmx libxxf86dga && sudo pacman -Syu
```

hope its works